Error passing a custom object from one Sampler to another: Cannot cast object 'CustomClass@instance' with class 'CustomClass' to class 'CustomClass'
In Jmeter 5.6.3, in a JSR223 sampler (Script language: groovy (Groovy 3.0.20 / Groovy Scripting Engine 2.0)), I am getting a runtime exception when trying to pass an object with a custom class from one JSR223 sampler to another:
message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'TestDataModel@5b28818c' with class 'TestDataModel' to class 'TestDataModel'
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'TestDataModel@5b28818c' with class 'TestDataModel' to class 'TestDataModel'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at java.scripting/javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:89) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:230) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:72) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'TestDataModel@5b28818c' with class 'TestDataModel' to class 'TestDataModel'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:404) ~[groovy-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:315) ~[groovy-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:243) ~[groovy-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:615) ~[groovy-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at Script16.run(Script16.groovy:9) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]

Here is the code of my Custom Class named "TestDataModel.groovy":
class TestDataModel {
    private String jmsMessageID;
    private long jmsTimestamp;
    private String targetValue;

    // Constructor
    public TestDataModel(String jmsMessageID, long jmsTimestamp, String targetValue) {
        this.jmsMessageID = jmsMessageID;
        this.jmsTimestamp = jmsTimestamp;
        this.targetValue = targetValue;
    }

    // Getters for accessing private fields
    public String getJmsMessageID() {
        return jmsMessageID;
    }

    public long getJmsTimestamp() {
        return jmsTimestamp;
    }

    public String getTargetValue() {
        return targetValue;
    }
}

The class is loaded to the JMeter classpath through the user.classpath config property.
JSR223 Sampler1:
import TestDataModel

List<TestDataModel> dataList = new ArrayList<>()

// Example: Adding message data to the list
dataList.add(new TestDataModel("ID1", System.currentTimeMillis(), "Value1"));
dataList.add(new TestDataModel("ID2", System.currentTimeMillis(), "Value2"));
dataList.add(new TestDataModel("ID3", System.currentTimeMillis(), "Value3"));


    // Example: Searching for a specific targetValue
    String targetValue1 = "Value2";
    for (TestDataModel testDataModel : dataList) {
      if (testDataModel.getTargetValue().equals(targetValue1)) {
          log.info("Found message with targetValue: " + targetValue1)
          log.info("JMSMessageID: " + testDataModel.getJmsMessageID())
          log.info("JMSTimestamp: " + testDataModel.getJmsTimestamp())
          break
      } else {
        log.info("Target message with targetValue: " + targetValue1 + " was not found")
        }
    }
    
    vars.putObject("customObject", dataList)
    
    def retrievedCustomObject = vars.getObject("customObject")
    
    
    // Example2: Searching for a specific targetValue
    String targetValue2 = "Value3";
    for (TestDataModel testDataModel : retrievedCustomObject) {
      if (testDataModel.getTargetValue().equals(targetValue2)) {
          log.info("Found message with targetValue: " + targetValue2)
          log.info("JMSMessageID: " + testDataModel.getJmsMessageID())
          log.info("JMSTimestamp: " + testDataModel.getJmsTimestamp())
          break
      } else {
        log.info("Target message with targetValue: " + targetValue2 + " was not found")
        }
    }

JSR223 Sampler2:
import TestDataModel

// Retrieve the customObject object from JMeter variables
def customObject = vars.getObject("customObject");

// Check if the object is not null
if (customObject != null) {
    // Iterate over the customObject
    for (TestDataModel data : customObject) {
        // Access data properties and perform actions as needed
        log.info("JMSMessageID: " + data.getJmsMessageID() + ", JMSTimestamp: " + data.getJmsTimestamp() + ", Value: " + data.getTargetValue());
        // Perform further processing here
    }
} else {
    log.info("customObject is null or not found in JMeter variables.");
}

I observed that if I user vars.PutObject() and vars.getObject() in the same JSR223 sampler it works without issues. However, it does not work from one JSR223 sampler to the other.
I would like to understand why this is happening. Any sort of explanation/solution would be greatly appreciated.

I cannot reproduce your issue with the simplified code:

First JSR223 Sampler:
def model = new TestDataModel('foo', 1L, 'bar')

def list = []

list.add(model)

vars.putObject('list', list)


Second JSR223 Sampler:
def model = vars.getObject('list')[0]

log.info('jmsMessageID: ' +  model.jmsMessageID)
log.info('jmsTimestamp: ' + model.jmsTimestamp)
log.info('targetValue: ' + model.targetValue)



Demo:

So most probably there is something wrong with your JMeter Classpath, i.e. you haven't restarted JMeter after compilation or changes to your "TestDataModel" class or there are 2 classes with the same name or whatever. Increase JMeter logging verbosity to DEBUG level and inspect CLASSPATH related entries.
Alternatively use a "clean" instance of JMeter, add your .class file to JMeter Classpath, restart JMeter and the issue will go away.

Thanks for looking into it. You said to add my ".class file to JMeter Classpath". Do you mean that my custom class file is not ok to have .groovy extension?

Indeed, I cannot reproduce the issue with your simplified code as well, but if you just copy-paste my samplers code in those 2 samplers you used for testing, you will see that the issue occurs. I just tried it now on a fresh script instance.

Just remove all TestDataModel instances from both scripts (including imports). Like instead List<TestDataModel> dataList = new ArrayList<>() just go for List dataList = new ArrayList<>(), etc. More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?

Yes, indeed, the solution from your comment in which I don't use a custom class at all avoids the error. Then I have to add objects like this:
dataList.add(["ID1", System.currentTimeMillis(), "Value1"])
Thanks!
It would have been interesting to understand technically why that error occurs in the first place though.

vars is a structure that does not automatically preserve the type information of the objects it stores due to the nature of the scripting engine, you either need to rely on raw types or explicitly perform casting of the received object.

Awesome answer! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. I would really appreciate it if you could exemplify such an explicit cast of a received object and make an update to your answer to integrate the information we discussed about in the comments section into your answer. Then I will mark your answer as a solution.

I would really appreciate if you would do your work yourself instead of asking others to do it for your for free. Then I will not tell you to **** right off

The idea was that you would not only be helping me punctually but the community as a whole. Anyone who will hit this issue in the future would be helped passively by you and your answer in the future.
Anyway, I am sorry if I offended you and I am very grateful for the wisdom you have shared with me so far, not only on this post but others as well. I really think that you are making a difference in the world. I hope that one day I will be able to pay it forward.
